# Android ListView to Intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

How do you set up an onClickListener for a list view so that each list view item takes you to a different intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the listener like this:

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = (String) myListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras("name", item);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

You use the `position` that you receive in the listener to get the item in the list at that position. Then you can bundle the item with the `Intent` and send it to the `Activity` (see code above with `putExtra`)

Comment: what did you do with the item variable? it does not reappear

Comment: The `item` is whatever you clicked on in the list. So presumably, you would use the `item` to figure out which `Activity` to launch. Considering we have no other details from you, it is impossible to say how you would use the `item` to pick an `Activity`.

Comment: Oh ok, I got it to work, thanks, but i am trying to change a drawable and it comes up with an error, do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: If my answer solved it for you, then you should accept my answer (click the check box next to it). You'll have to post a separate question about the image view and I'll try to help you. It is too hard to try to solve problems in the comments. Post a link to it and I will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

If you are extending ListActivity then you can do something like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(present_activity.this,target_activty.class);
            intent.putExtras("key",item);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

Hope this helps..:)

Comment: hmmm... but how does defining the string item help if you do not use it later in the intent?, thanks btw

Comment: @user1236269 i changed my answer liffle bit.please see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are populating the list through an adapter you can use onListItemClick() which will give you the listView, the view clicked, and the position in the list.

From there you can use a switch on the position to start the different activities. Or if your listview is more dynamic you can have the view in the list save which activity it wants to open in its tag. (view.setTag("acivityName")) and use something like this to start the activity:

```
String activityName = view.getTag();
i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Class.forName(activityName));
startActivity(i);
```